# How do I get metric names in Grafana's message template?

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-alerts

I'm setting up Grafana v8.3.4 alerts. If I use a template like the following

```
{{ define "test_message" }}

{{ range .Alerts.Firing }}
{{ print .ValueString }} 
{{ end }}

{{ end }}
```

[image]

And test the e-mail notification using this template and the predefined message:

[image]

I get:

```
[ metric='foo' labels={instance=bar} value=10 ]
```

In the example above there's only one metric, but there could be more.

**Question: Is there any way to loop through the returned metrics and display it as a table in the e-mail?**

It would look something like:

| Metric Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| foo | 10 |
| x | 22 |
| y | 7 |

...

**[UPDATE 6/24/2022]**
@Luis Almeida's answer led me to the right path, so I'm marking it as the correct answer even though my final solution was a little different.

Here are a couple of other links that also helped:

[How to template annotations and labels - Grafana's Official Documentatio n](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/fundamentals/annotation-label/variables-label-annotation/)
[Unified Alerting Grafana 8 | Prometheus | Victoria | Telegraf | Notifications | Alert Templating](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtmmhLraSnE)

Comment: Hi @EduardoCMB can you post your final solution?

Comment: Hi @Froxz... it's been a while, and I'm not sure if I switched gear in the end... let me see what I can find it. I'll be in touch soon.

Comment: @EduardoCMB, please advise how to delete the Value field from the alert notification email and to only keep the Labels field as displayed on the screenshot.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNsl1.png (or https://ibb.co/rmdNwYz if another link doesn't work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you basically have are multiple alerts (which one has a metric defined by **[ metric='foo' labels={instance=bar} value=10 ]**) and you want to pull all this alerts in a table?

I'm using a classic condition with a median function in order to remove eventual outliers btw.
If you want to access the value in:

- the first condition you should put **{{ $values.B0.Value }}**
- the second condition you should put **{{ $values.B1.Value }}**
- the n-th condition you should put **{{ $values.Bn.Value }}**
  [image: classic condition]
  If you want to access the a normal query value I think the variable  **{{ $values.A.Value }}** where **A** is the query's name, but since grafana documentation for versions below 9 disappear I cannot confirm that

You can use annotations to give a more readable metric's name as depicted in the image above.

I believe that html tags are escaped since html tags appears on the template as text. So now that you have the annotations with the given values you have to edit the default email template that is in
`/usr/share/grafana/public/emails/ng_alert_notification.html`

*Warning: Do a backup of this file just in case something goes wrong*

In the image bellow is how annotations are render in the email, now you just have to substitute that code with some code that renders a table. I believe that now it's fairly simple to do it yourself. (I didn't put the code here since I am not that comfortable with golang).
If you want something different you can analise this file and change as you want.
[image: ng_alert_notification]
Note: To take effect the changes done in ng_alert_notification.html you have to restart grafana server

[Good looking HTML and CSS example](https://dev.to/dcodeyt/creating-beautiful-html-tables-with-css-428l)

Note: I'm using v8.5.2

Answer (score 0):

As [Luis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11888436/luis-almeida) said, you can access values in the description programmatically:

Raw value string:

```
[ var='B0' metric='Value' labels={job_name=some-job-123} value=1202 ], 
[ var='B1' metric='Value' labels={job_name=another-job-234} value=601 ]
```

In the Alert description:

```
{{ range $k, $v := $values }}
{{ $k }}={{ $v }}
The value is {{ $v }} and the labels are {{ $v.Labels }}
{{ $v.Labels.job_name }}
{{ index $v.Labels "job_name"}}
{{ end }}
```

Alert output:

```
B0=1202
The value is 1202 and the labels are map[job_name:some-job-123]
some-job-123
some-job-123

B1=601
The value is 601 and the labels are map[job_name:another-job-234]
another-job-234
another-job-234
```